# Access map inside array in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, maps

How do I access map inside an array?

NOTE:

1. arr is an array that has 2 elements, and each element contains a map
2. arr[0] and arr[1] has places and foods but in different index

Code:

```
def arr = [[places:[[city:'New York', states:'Texas'], [city:'Chicago', states:'Alaska']], 
foods:[[drinks:'Soda', snack:'Fries'], [drinks:'Milk', snack: 'Cereals']]],
[foods:[[drinks:'Beer', snack:'Chips'], [drinks:'Milk', snack: 'Cereals']],
places:[[city:'New York', states:'Montana'], [city:'Austin', states:'Alaska']]]]


println("${arr[0].foods} \n")
println("${arr[1].foods}")
```

Expected Output:

```
[[drinks:Soda, snack:Fries], [drinks:Milk, snack: Cereals]]

[[drinks:Beer, snack:Chips], [drinks:Milk, snack: Cereals]]
```

Actual Output:

```
[null,[drinks:Soda, snack:Fries], [drinks:Milk, snack: Cereals]]]

[null,[[drinks:Beer, snack:Chips], [drinks:Milk, snack: Cereals]],null]
```

Comment: `echo arr[0].name` and `echo arr[0]['name']` should work. Just remove unnecessary quotes.

Comment: what do you mean by `it wont work` ? any error message?

Comment: ```println("${arr[0].places}")``` gives me an output of ```[[[city:New York, states:Texas], [city:Chicago,states:Alaska]], null]```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide: input as executable code, expected output and actual output

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: The `def arr = ...` part is not a valid code

Comment: Its just an array with 2 maps inside

Comment: "The def arr = ... part is not a valid code " = @daggett If you look at the answer I left below or look at https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/75e6ec344b929434448a892f3b378ae3 you can see a valid version of the List of Map.

Comment: Above I mentioned the answer I left.  I have removed the answer as it didn't answer the question which I misunderstood.  I am mentioning the deletion only because there is a comment above that mentions an answer that some folks won't be able to see.  I am sorry for the noise.

Comment: The answer I had left, and the gist linked above addresses "How do I access map inside an array?" but it doesn't address the follow on stuff that @monami left as comments on that answer.